# Using strong in cdata php - Magento

Tags: php, javascript, magento

[image]

I am trying to make th e 'Search' part of "My Search" bold but I'm not getting anywhere with it.

I am trying to edit:

app/design/fontend/base/default/template/cataloguesearch/form.mini.phtml

If I add strong or span it looks like this:

[image]

The code in question is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm(
            'search_mini_form', 
            'search', 
            '<?php echo $this->__('MY <span>SEARCH...</span>') ?>'
        );
        searchForm.initAutocomplete(
            '<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 
            'search_autocomplete'
        );
    //]]>
</script>
```

I take it you can not use strong or span in that areas - is there another way of doing it?

I have a look but am not sure how to search for something so specific as this, no luck so far.

Comment: is it an input field  ? you cannot use HTML in these field ..

Comment: ok thanks but is there a work around for it, can I declare a var then call that one?

Comment: nop, you have to use a totally custom component that allows you to style your input with HTML .. it's doable with JS maybe there is a jquery plugin somewhere

Comment: ah no way, is that it? thanks for your reply but that sucks! If anyone else would like to offer more of a solutions it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Bixi

Comment: You're trying to style a string within an input field.  You cannot do this by just using a span or pure CSS, as input fields cannot contain HTML elements.  It would require some custom javascript to achieve.  I personally think amount of effort involved for such a simple result wouldn't be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place HTML inside input fields. There is no way to highlight or bold only certain words, unless you do this a different way - i.e. absolutely positioning the tag over top (or behind) an empty text field.

(updated)

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache ? Could you use the path hint to see if you're editing the good file ?

Comment: Yes I am clearing cache and i am editing the correct file, based on the reply by Bixi above it isn't even possible - anyones else have any input on this? I can't be the only person who has encountered this issue...